# Machine learning to cluster or classify programs

Tags: machine-learning, code-analysis

I am working on a way to represent C/C++ program code. in order to create a dataset and do some machine learning after that.

Thinking about code as text and doing some text mining doesn't seem correct for me. because i'm more interesseted by the semantic and precision of calculations.

So what could be a good representative vector of programms ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you don't want to represent your programs as sequences of tokens.

Remember you don't have to actually represent code as words. If you're interested in semantic relationships you can use higher-level descriptions - for example you can use parse trees of expressions rather than tokens.

You can also take this grammatical approach further and represent the whole program as parse tree in some grammar rather than a sequence of tokens. There are recurrent networks that can handle tree-structured data.

Comment: I agree with you, there are semantic relationships that count a lot. this is why i don't want to use tokens or n-grams with or without features selection. I can use my grammer tree parser. but as an entry in machine learning, i need a vector. what's the best way to transform a tree into a vector (array) ? thank you.